# This simple python code isnt working?

Tags: python, maze

Whenever an output should result in a change of shield, the program just says 'You have 5 shields' followed by 'You Win'. I think I might have made a mistake when passing over the variables from one function to the next. Thank you in advance for the help!

```
def main():
    while TakeTurn(word,shield) == False:
        if shield == 1:
            word1 = "shield"
        else:
            word1 = "shields"
        print ("You have", shield, word1,)
    if shield < 1:
        print ("Sorry! You ran out of shields! You lose!")
    else:
        print ("You win")
#This function is the actual 'game' and will deterine what happens to the character    
def TakeTurn(word1,shield1):
    time.sleep(1.5)
    #This means that when the user reaches 0 shields, they lose.
    if shield1 < 1:
        return True
    #Whatever the user inputs will not actually affect the outcome
    print ("You have reached", word1 ,"junction.\nDo you want to turn left (L), turn right (R) or go straight ahead(S)?")
    turning = input()
    #This is a simple instruction that means that the first time you come to a junction, it will say 'a junction' but the second time it will say 'another junction'
    word1 = "another"
    #This 'if' statement means that the program will only continue if the user has inputed the letters 'L', 'R' or 'S'
    elif turning not in ["L","R","S","l","r","s"] :
        time.sleep (0.7)
        print ("Sorry, I didn't understand that")
        TakeTurn()
    else:
        choice = randint (1,10)
    #This is just going to display a random message which will affect the outcome
    time.sleep (1)
    if choice == 1:
        print ("You have found the exit!")
        return True
    elif choice == 2:
        print ("You have found a shield!")
        time.sleep(1)
        shield1 = shield1 +1
        return False
    elif choice == 3:
        print ("You have found two shields!")
        time.sleep(1)
        shield1 = shield1 +2
        return False
    elif choice == 4:
        print ("You have found three shields!")
        time.sleep(1)
        shield1 = shield1 +3
        return False
    elif choice == 5:
        print ("A fairy has jumped into your pants!")
        time.sleep(2)
        print ("You lose two shields")
        time.sleep(1)
        shield1 = shield1 -2
        return False
    elif choice == 6:
        treasurechest(shield1)
        return False
    elif choice == 7:
        print ("You have tripped over a log!")
        time.sleep(2)
        print ("You lose a shield")
        time.sleep(1)
        shield1 = shield1 -1
        return False
    elif choice == 8:
        print ("An angry teenager is staring at you in the eye.")
        time.sleep(2.5)
        print ("He uses laziness...")
        time.sleep(1.5)
        print ("It's super effective!")
        time.sleep(1)
        print ("You lose three shields")
        time.sleep(1)
        shield1 = shield1 -3
        return False
    elif choice == 9:
        print ("You have encountered an ogre...")
        time.sleep(1.5)
        print ("He bashes you over the head with a steel bar")
        time.sleep(2)
        print ("You lose two shields")
        time.sleep(1)
        shield1 = shield1 -2
        return False
    else:
        print ("A goblin aproaches and says the following:")
        time.sleep(2)
        goblin(shield1)
        return False
```

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com might be a better place to ask such questions

Comment: No, it wouldn't @kroolik.. Code Review is only for working code. If you aren't a member of the site in question it's best to _never_ suggest another one.

Comment: You should only post fully working code on code review and this isnt working

Comment: Where are `word` and `shield` initially assigned, and to what values?

Comment: What are the default values of shield and word?

Comment: word and shield are assigned at the beginning, word is 'a' and shield is 5; I also made word a global variable

Comment: Can you post your global variables please?

Comment: You should give names to states and actions. You could define a dictionary for state transitions given each possible action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should refactor `main` and `TakeTurn` to make `shield` and `word` explicit arguments and `return` values. This prevents relying on scope for access to variables, without having to use `global` (which is usually a bad sign):

```
def main(shield, word):
    while True:
        shield, word, finished = TakeTurn(shield, word)
        if finished:
            break
        word1 = "shield" if shield == 1 else "shields"
        print ("You have {0} {1}".format(shield, word1))
    if shield < 1:
        print ("Sorry! You ran out of shields! You lose!")
    else:
        print ("You win")
```

And have `TakeTurn` return multiple values accordingly, e.g.:

```
elif choice == 3:
    print ("You have found two shields!")
    time.sleep(1)
    shield1 = shield1 + 2
    return shield1, word1, False
```

---

You could make things neater by making `choices` a list of dictionaries and picking randomly from it:

```
choices = [{"texts": [("You have found two shields!", 1)], 
            "shield change": 2, "return": False}, 
           {"texts": [("You have encountered an ogre...", 1.5), 
                      ("He bashes you over the head with a steel bar", 2),
                      ("You lose two shields", 1)],
            "shield change": -2, "return": False},
           ...]
```

Then your main section, instead of all the `elif`s, becomes simply:

```
choice = random.choice(choices)
for text, sleep_time in choice['texts']:
    print(text)
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
shield1 += choice['shield change']
return shield1, word1, choice['return']
```

Comment: I did what you said but now it has come up with this TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable

Comment: Presumably because you haven't changed all of the return values from `TakeTurn`.